# How to query multi level bullet point x.x.x in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, hierarchy

Typical employee data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41d151/1/0 as example data

I need to get result like this

```
    +-----+-----------+-------+
    | ID  |   NAME    | rnum  |
    +-----+-----------+-------+
    | 100 | King      |     1 |
    | 102 | De Haan   |   1.1 |
    | 103 | Hunold    | 1.1.1 |
    | 148 | Cambrault |   1.2 |
    | 170 | Fox       | 1.2.1 |
    | 169 | Bloom     | 1.2.3 |
    |          <...>          |
    | 147 | Errazuriz |   1.3 |
    | 166 | Ande      | 1.3.1 |
    | 167 | Banda     | 1.3.2 |
    |          <...>           
    | 521 | Smith     | 5.14.3|
    +-----+-----------+-------+
```

Main problem is *rnum* generation. I can't pass *e.level_* to subquery.

```
WITH data AS (-- more useful employee list
              SELECT id, name, level_order, level level_, manager_id, CONNECT_BY_ROOT id root_manager
              FROM employee
              CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id
              START WITH manager_id IS null
              ORDER BY level, level_order)
SELECT e.id, e.name, sys_connect_by_path((SELECT e2.rnum
                                          FROM (-- employee at same level, sorted and numerated
                                                SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t.level_order) rnum, t.employee_id
                                                FROM data t
                                                WHERE t.level_ = e.level_
                                                ORDER BY t.level_order) e2
                                          WHERE e2.employee_id = e.employee_id), '.')
FROM employee e
CONNECT BY PRIOR e.employee_id = e.manager_id
START WITH e.manager_id is null
/
```

Is there a way to pass *level* to nested query?
Or query same data in more elegant way? Looks like one of common case scenario for me.

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure? You have added the tag for PL/SQL which indicates you want a stored procedure or function as an answer.

Comment: Query. PL/SQL function usage is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two hierarchical queries, though it looks like there ought to be a way to simplify this further:

```
select employee_id,
  last_name,
  ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(rn, '.'), '.') as rnum
from (
  select employee_id, manager_id, last_name,
    dense_rank() over (partition by level, manager_id order by last_name) as rn
  from employees
  start with manager_id is null
  connect by manager_id = prior employee_id
)
start with manager_id is null
connect by manager_id = prior employee_id
order by employee_id;
```

which with the subset of IDs in your SQL Fiddle (which is for MySQL rather than Oracle, oddly) gives:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID LAST_NAME                 RNUM                          
----------- ------------------------- ------------------------------
        100 King                      1                             
        102 De Haan                   1.2                           
        103 Hunold                    1.2.1                         
        104 Ernst                     1.2.1.2                       
        105 Austin                    1.2.1.1                       
        106 Pataballa                 1.2.1.4                       
        107 Lorentz                   1.2.1.3                       
        147 Errazuriz                 1.3                           
        148 Cambrault                 1.1                           
        166 Ande                      1.3.1                         
        167 Banda                     1.3.2                         
        168 Ozer                      1.1.5                         
        169 Bloom                     1.1.2                         
        170 Fox                       1.1.3                         
        171 Smith                     1.1.6                         
        172 Bates                     1.1.1                         
        173 Kumar                     1.1.4
```

or with the full default HR schema table gives:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID LAST_NAME                 RNUM                          
----------- ------------------------- ------------------------------
        100 King                      1                             
        101 Kochhar                   1.7                           
        102 De Haan                   1.2                           
        103 Hunold                    1.2.1                         
        104 Ernst                     1.2.1.2                       
        105 Austin                    1.2.1.1                       
        106 Pataballa                 1.2.1.4                       
        107 Lorentz                   1.2.1.3                       
        108 Greenberg                 1.7.2                         
        109 Faviet                    1.7.2.2                       
        110 Chen                      1.7.2.1                       
...
        204 Baer                      1.7.1                         
        205 Higgins                   1.7.3                         
        206 Gietz                     1.7.3.1                       

107 rows selected.
```

Either way it doesn't quite match your suggested result; there is only one top-level manager rather than the five your example output expects, for example.

If you are using 11gR2 you could use a recursive CTE instead, which is perhaps easier to follow and (to me anyway) more intuitive:

```
with rcte (employee_id, last_name, rnum) as (
  select e.employee_id, e.last_name,
    to_char(dense_rank() over (order by e.last_name))
  from employees e
  where manager_id is null
  union all
  select e.employee_id, e.last_name,
    r.rnum ||'.'|| dense_rank() over (partition by r.rnum order by e.last_name)
  from rcte r
  join employees e on e.manager_id = r.employee_id
)
select *
from rcte
order by employee_id;
```

which gets the same results.

I've guessed that you are treating each level in last-name order, but you can adjust if that isn't what you actually want.

If you want to order the result by those levels then a brute-force way is to tokenise the generated `rnum` value:

```
...
order by
  to_number(regexp_substr(rnum, '[^.]+', 1, 1)) nulls first,
  to_number(regexp_substr(rnum, '[^.]+', 1, 2)) nulls first,
  to_number(regexp_substr(rnum, '[^.]+', 1, 3)) nulls first,
  to_number(regexp_substr(rnum, '[^.]+', 1, 4)) nulls first;
```

and with your smaller subset again that now gives:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID LAST_NAME                 RNUM                          
----------- ------------------------- ------------------------------
        100 King                      1                             
        148 Cambrault                 1.1                           
        172 Bates                     1.1.1                         
        169 Bloom                     1.1.2                         
        170 Fox                       1.1.3                         
        173 Kumar                     1.1.4                         
        168 Ozer                      1.1.5                         
        171 Smith                     1.1.6                         
        102 De Haan                   1.2                           
        103 Hunold                    1.2.1                         
        105 Austin                    1.2.1.1                       
        104 Ernst                     1.2.1.2                       
        107 Lorentz                   1.2.1.3                       
        106 Pataballa                 1.2.1.4                       
        147 Errazuriz                 1.3                           
        166 Ande                      1.3.1                         
        167 Banda                     1.3.2
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e06f096e96067623c6cc3e2ca0ab1134)

Comment: Recursive CTE, would never ever have thought of it in million years.